# ADXL 335 Accelerometer incorrect Output. z and y axes always the same

Tags: accelerometer

[image]I have an ADXL 335 Accelerometer. I'm checking its output voltage values using a multimeter and I'm consistently getting the z and y axes giving me the same result. How do I trouble shoot this problem?

I have attached a picture of the accelerometer. The male to male wires were used for voltage readings. The 5 coloured header pins are providing data to the MSP that we are using to send information to the laptop. The MSP is powering the Accelerometer.

I have checked the resistance between the z and y pins, there is no visible resistance.

Comment: Do you have pictures of your board?

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps the Z and Y axis output pins are shorted together.  Measuring resistance between them with the power off might be informative.

Comment: We checked the resistance and found there wasn't any between them or any other pin on the board.

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for your help. We figured out the solution. It was to do with the breadboard.